# Bash backtick vs parenthesis

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I read that the classic form of command substitution uses backticks and (...) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.
Yet, below code produces different output. what is the difference ?

```
#backticks.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`echo Hello!`   # Assigns result of 'echo' command to 'a' ...
echo $a   # output: Hello!
```

---

```
#parenthesis.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=(echo Hello!)   # Assigns result of 'echo' command to 'a' ...
echo $a  # output: echo
```

---

Comment: In the manual, it's documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: Just to add - we've fixed the formatting for you. In future, pre tags work, or just use the {} button. You can also see help for more information on the specific dialect of markdown used here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing here is `$`.

There is 2 forms of command substitution on bash, backticks, as exemplified by you, and enclosing by `$(command)`.

What you should use is:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(echo Hello!)

echo $a
```

Comment: and to extend the explanation: `a=(echo Hello!)` declares the variable `a` as an *array* containing 2 elements, "echo" and "Hello!". With an array, `echo $a` is equivalent to `echo ${a[0]}` (the first element of the array)

Comment: This extended explanation is very helpful!